# Functional derivative of gradient of cross product

Tags: derivatives, variational-analysis

I need to find functional derivative of the following function with respect to $\eta$

$F = \int[(n\times \nabla\eta) + (m\times \nabla\eta)]^2dr$

Where, n and m are vectors and constant, $\eta$ is a function defined in space

Thanks

Comment: As opposed to a dysfunctional derivative? :-) Take $F(\eta+h)-F(\eta)$ and look for the linear terms.

Comment: I am not sure if this falls under that category